# Reopening windows minimized with Super+D

Tags: unity, launcher

I've noticed this a while ago and I have no idea what to do to fix it or even if this behaviour is expected.

Lets say I have 3 gedit windows open. Then I keep working on the terminal, firefox etc. The point is that I can no longer see the gedit windows. To clear the clutter I press Super+D which basically hides everything.

If I click the gedit icon on the launcher bar I open the last opened window of gedit and if I click it again it spreads all gedit windows so I can choose which one I want. So far so good!

At this moment a weird behaviour happens. In the spread view, if I choose anything besides the last opened gedit window, then I can't open it. Basically it seems like ubuntu is still telling the window to remain hidden from the last Super+D.

Now I have to press super+D (which hides everything again because there is one gedit window open) then super+D again (which reveals everything) and now it works and I can double click the gedit icon and select the other gedit windows that weren't the last one opened.

I really don't see how this could be a feature. The obvious intuitive behaviour when clicking on a window on the spread is that that window comes to the top of the screen.